# Writing arbitrary unicode to file

Tags: python, python-unicode

I have been attempting to output arbitrary characters (literally of any kind) to a generated file. Consider the below starting code (could probably be written better but just wanted to get something work right now).

```
from random import randint

def alphanumrand(n):
    bounds = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F']

    string_buffer = ''
    for index in range(0,n):
        string_buffer += bounds[randint(0,14)]
    return string_buffer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print alphanumrand(2097152).decode('hex')
```

Which works great; take the following sample output:

```
Öõ╔i§g┬Ø}>#àæƒÒ1È/-Q|Ð┬Ô/µåQàà¡#ÎKnÚ4+▀Ö▲↔u│öCü╗§íJ
uX▒ý┘w©╔SÄ¹4)&Cié▓B↔↑rÏ×2O>↔gªE]±Ñ∟"N4←$¹ÖM═┤#R┴¼-Ä
Ûý(v:ÈRC┘ F┌èGB/©↔╦mCØ*ƒ[ýw┼J*=T‼å╩]ñuö¶╗^[╬┼î3Ñê²H
7:┬┴)r∟¬9ôEw±\┐§↕¿fºXã¯H$<)tÆ3?äAÊƒ←+>®ÌË■ã¤«▀╣|▬▬↕
ý¬sÚ╩ØAèX¢È¦I▄<ÿ°ı↨h8º+½ù²$←yezj9}7ËÀ»5/;·Á┼¾ÕúÒÛ┘┤
U╔¸Þ■;↔²%∟╩═Þ┤Æ◄ó¶Öl=Ñ▒Ú╝ü~wïåbzå*À¼~/╬‗BÀ´®£ }▒ïÚ 
∟ma§ã"_5┼═║Ñx3y"§U/‼]Gß.X}wií◄┴ñj¬a÷I?7·⌂àc?wÌZsZv←
├2ûuB║®_ Ï╚S▼[¬ò↨E§Inz$HàU²Ê╗kÅ¼Â½·┐mxYÑ╔çäÔ!b·åÒ∟-
bf".«M'T\ø_Ø×edaâK®Æ┤¹═╗─õãË¡◄┬¤©?Ð→ª▀jÂîQ┐9Êƒ=┘3Ý↑
À┬ÙU§ou~Ë╩c╠,¢ú}╣À<>┤→u╚Qõ▄╬dê÷jÄ§Or→·º↓rÀ╔B¦3°L¬±Ý
H╦▓à?┤;è┴X↕½‗▒o¼¤;³÷Cz·ü_RYùâ├UÍLØzÂ²ÌçZ²¬i$ÞÛÈ"║âj
"¿┴¹¼¾%(K┘|║éBZ\ëÔ%◄▲‗¶D■?cé³¤&±êÊ«v⌂qªG}of┼÷Ñ³M!-Ù
gÆ╩╝2qR|¿å÷ÙÂ‗¾|ï∟¶▀eå¦~AXKß4⌂▀═mýzæ²ÿ↕▒%ìÐMÒÅmS!¥§
+G▼╠↨v■↓xËMÐÞoÅA¿ëu╬╩─®t$ºrK{t¿üÑ5¸→é%ûn¿Ý©í▒1#┘▓4┴
E©¸╩↕vq6¯k┼CQ╝xû╝╣/%Ô4║ÈÌe¢¹è]‼{q ƒºÛ←óÔ ■ÿ.Å▲↕3'¬ı
```

Except I cannot find any legal way to output this to a file whether it be with `utf-8` or any other codec for that matter.

The following `UnicodeDecodeError` exception messages may also be of some use.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 104-105: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1: invalid start byte

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If you haven't noticed by now; I'm terrible with unicode and should probably just research more about it instead.

N.B - Using Python 2.7

Comment: Do you need to have an even distribution over all unicode characters? If you just generate random bytes (0-255) and write them to the file, you can avoid needing to deal with unicode at all. Your file won't be valid UTF-8, but that may not matter.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Tried that already, that's how I got the last `UnicodeDecodeError` exception.

Comment: @ThomasK Indeed it wouldn't matter at all; the idea however is to give crazy ugly characters over to a web server to fuzz test the application with characters generated on the fly--I'm not sure how effective that alternative would be but I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify any encoding, just do `File.write(alphanumrand(2097152).decode('hex'))`. This will write the bytes you've generated.

This works for me:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Writing...'
    with open('test.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(alphanumrand(2097152).decode('hex'))

    print 'Done'

    with open('test.txt') as f:
        print repr(f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I should've mentioned in the original question by now that the other half of the string itself does indeed require `utf-8` encoding as it's being imported from another file. I will probably rewrite everything to implement it using a similar method mentioned in the comments. Thanks!